# Select aggregate ignores where cause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to transform an existing view into a format I can work with.

The view `vw_temp_appHoursLastTwoEntries` looks like this:

```
RowNumber | PersNr | Client | Localtion | Agent | Date       | Calweek | Year
----------+--------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+---------+------
1         | 123    | 1      | 1         | ag-01 | 2020-01-01 | 1       | 2021
2         | 123    | 1      | 1         | ag-01 | 2020-01-03 | 1       | 2021
1         | 9999   | 1      | 4         | ag-01 | 2020-01-01 | 1       | 2021
2         | 9999   | 1      | 4         | ag-01 | 2020-01-07 | 1       | 2021
```

I need this data in a different format that would look like this:

```
PersNr | Client | Localtion | Agent | minDate    | MaxDate    | DateDiff | Calweek | Year
-------+--------+-----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+---------+-------
123    | 1      | 1         | ag-01 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 | 3        | 1       | 2021
9999   | 1      | 4         | ag-01 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-07 | 7        | 1       | 2021
```

in the original format, one person has only two rows (`RowNumber 1 and 2`). I'd like to match each column and have the min and max date as well as the difference in a new view.

**my Code:**

```
select a.persnr, a.client, a.location, a.agent, a.calweek, a.year, 
max(a.date) as maxdate, min(b.date) as mindate

    , DATEDIFF(day,a.date,b.date) as dDiff

    from vw_temp_appHoursLastTwoEntries a
       left join vw_temp_appHoursLastTwoEntries b on 
       a.persnr = b.persnr and a.client = b.client and
       a.agent = b.agent and a.date = b.date

    where a.date != b.date and DATEDIFF(day,a.date,b.date) != 0
    or (a.date is not null and b.date is not null) 

    group by a.persnr, a.client, a.location, a.agent, a.calweek, a.year, DATEDIFF(day,a.date,b.date)
```

**The issue:**

I'm currently getting back values where it seems like the where cause does not take effect but I don't understand why.

`a.date != b.date` should not return rows where `min-` and `maxdates` are the same. The `datediff` does not return any other value then `0` even when the `min-` and `maxdates` are different.

Comment: Is this condition `a.date = b.date` really a part of the `ON` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is what you want:

```
declare @Test table (RowNumber int, PersNr int, Client int, Localtion int, Agent varchar(5), [Date] date, Calweek int, [Year] int);

insert into @Test (RowNumber, PersNr, Client, Localtion, Agent, [Date], Calweek, [Year])
values
(1, 123, 1, 1, 'ag-01', '2020-01-01', 1, 2021),
(2, 123, 1, 1, 'ag-01', '2020-01-03', 1, 2021),
(1, 9999, 1, 4, 'ag-01', '2020-01-01', 1, 2021),
(2, 9999, 1, 4, 'ag-01', '2020-01-07', 1, 2021);

select a.PersNr, a.Client, a.Localtion, a.Agent, a.Calweek, a.[Year]
    , max(a.[date]) as maxdate
    , min(b.[date]) as mindate
    , abs(datediff(day,a.[date],b.[date])) as dDiff
from @Test a
left join @Test b on 
    a.persnr = b.persnr and a.client = b.client and
    a.agent = b.agent --and a.[date] = b.[date]
where (/*a.[date] != b.[date] and*/ datediff(day,a.[date],b.[date]) != 0)
  and /*  not OR */ (a.[date] is not null and b.[date] is not null) 
group by a.persnr, a.client, a.Localtion, a.agent, a.calweek, a.[Year], abs(datediff(day,a.[date],b.[date]));
```

Returns:

| PersNr | Client | Localtion | Agent | Calweek | Year | maxdate | mindate | dDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 | ag-01 | 1 | 2021 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-01 | 2 |
| 9999 | 1 | 4 | ag-01 | 1 | 2021 | 2020-01-07 | 2020-01-01 | 6 |

As Giorgos points out, you don't want to join on `a.[date] = b.[date]` because your `where` clause specifically filters that condition out.

The main issue was using `OR` instead of `AND`, you want to ensure that both `date` values are not null so that is an `AND` condition.

I am also assuming that `dDiff` is for debugging purposes only, which as you have it kept the rows from grouping, but you can group them by using the absolute value (`abs`).

You also don't need to test `a.[date] != b.[date]` because that is already true by virtue of `datediff(day,a.[date],b.[date]) != 0`.

Please use this form of DDL+DML (or a temp table) in future to provide sample data for us to work with (it gives you a minimal reproducible example also which is never a bad thing, because I picked up a number of typos in your query while copying it).

Comment: thank you very much! second time you saved me :) totally missed that and thank you so much for your explaination!